# Pressure buildup in a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

How to model the fluid's pressure evolution over time and distance in a pipe, from inlet to outlet, assuming the fluid is water.

Say that I have a pipe filled with a fluid with pressure P1 and flowing with Q1 steadily across the pipe.

Now I changed to P2 and Q2 at the inlet, how do I get P(t), and Q(t) at different lengths across the pipe, until the pressure stabilize again.

In other words I need to model the pressure evolution, at different points across the pipe as time proceeds.

Comment: Are you interested in how such problems are solved or do you want to solve?

Comment: How about both :)

Comment: What approximation do you intend to solve?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by approximation, but I think you mean like:
Constant density, quasi-steady or even steady flow, like in water distributions networks

Comment: What I am looking for is the most basic approximation, where I end up with a system of equations to allow me to model and calculate, (motion/P/Q) of the fluid in a pipe at any given time.
I come from electrical engineering background, and I want to learn fluid mechanics, I want to see how such models are developed with basic approximations, so I can create my own models later for more complex ones, like gas, and turbulent flow.

Comment: From your last comment it seems you need to solve the full Navier Stokes equation for an incompressible flow.

Comment: @AsItis As a basic model for calculating pressure waves in pipelines, we usually use the Navier-Stokes equations for compressible flow. The flow parameters are averaged over the cross section of the pipe, which reduces the dimension of the problem to 1 + 1.